# Can GlimpseDbConnection be configured in one central location to have the SQL tab collect data

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, glimpse

I have successfully configured Glimpse with out of the box settings and an addition to the web.config file to support it running both remote and locally. However I cannot get the SQL tab to display any data, nor is it clickable.

I am using a linq to sql data connection for the Repository layer and make calls to retrieve data via the Data Context object. After further research of the problem I came across the following documentation that suggests this anomaly as a known limitation. http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Manual-ADO-Integration

So I following the instructions and modified a call to one method of many within the app to use the GlimpseDbConnection object as a wrapper my DataContext but the SQL tab is still unclickable and there is no apparent data being collected either.

What I'd like to try next to resolve my problem and also the question for this post is; is there any way that the GlimpseDbConnection object may be implemented directly within the dbml.designer.cs class so I don't have to potentially go through every place within the application where the DataContext is being called to make the referenced modification?

```
var db = new ApplicationDataContext(new GlimpseDbConnection(new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString)));
db.UpdateReportDetails(ReportID,
                       ReportName,
                       ReportURL,
                       null, 
                       null, 
                       ReportDescription,
                       ReportComment,
                       LanID,
                       ActiveIndicator);
```

Comment: Can you share the code around how you are creating your DataContext?

Comment: Sure, I've added the code for how I'm creating my DataContext with Glimpse. I believe this is what you're asking for? I am using linqToSql Data Classes in the solution. The Tab started showing up in Chrome but IE8 apparently has issues working properly with Glimpse. I would however ideally like to initialize Glimpse within my DataContext constructor instead of creating a new instance everywhere I want Glimpse to intercept.